# how to add BOLD feature for the user in meteor autoform field?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2

am using autoform in my project. One of my field is textarea "6 rows" for description. is it possible to add BOLD feature for the users to highlight the important points in the description?

and is it possible to give the users the ability to add images as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best idea here is to use packages. So, for the images it depends on what you mean: upload or put links.

> Case 1 - Upload

If you want only the links it is easy and you can match them with a regex. But otherwise, I suggest Dropbox API. I used it for one of my apps, so I am sure it works and it is not difficult to implement. First, add [CollectionFS](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/standard-packages) and then [the dropbox package](https://atmospherejs.com/cfs/dropbox). Then create a developer account at dropbox and follow the documentation of the package. Just an [example](https://atmospherejs.com/babrahams/editable-text-wysiwyg-bootstrap-3)

> Case 2 - Save Base64

I really do not suggest the second way although it is easier (just so much pressure on the database).

> Concerning the user input

Again the simplest way is a package. There are some of them which give you the opportunity for a relation of the collection with the autoform. I do not know if here an integration with Dropbox is possible but if you go this way consider the Base64 possibility. But it again related to parsing the image with a regex.